# Laravel livewire - how to pass geo coordinates of user to livewire component

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I am trying to send geo coordinates (latitude and longitude) of user to a livewire component to load nearby places. However I am unable to send it because they are javascript variables. Question is how do I send a javascript variable to a livewire component?

Here is what I have done so far.

```
# home.blade.php

@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <script>
        var latitude;
        var longitude;
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            function success(pos) {
                var loc = pos.coords;
                latitude = loc.latitude;
                longitude = loc.longitude;
            }, 
            function error(err) {
                // console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
                $.getJSON('https://ipinfo.io/geo', function(response) { 
                    var loc = response.loc.split(',');
                    latitude = parseFloat(loc[0]);
                    longitude = parseFloat(loc[1]);
                });
            }, options
        );
    </script>
    @livewire('nearby')
@endsection
@livewireScripts
```

```
# Nearby.php 

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;
use App\Listing;

class Nearby extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    public function render()
    {
        $listings = Listing::paginate(9);
        return view('livewire.nearby', [
            'listings' => $listings
        ]);
    }
}
```

```
# nearby.blade.php - livewire blade

<div class="relative bg-gray-50 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
    <div class="relative max-w-6xl mx-auto">
        <div class="mt-12 grid gap-5 max-w-lg mx-auto lg:grid-cols-3 lg:max-w-none">
            @foreach($listings as $listing)
                @include('components.listing',['listing'=>$listing])
            @endforeach
        </div>
        <div class="text-center mx-auto mt-3">
            {{ $listings->links() }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll need to emit an event globally from you script. like this:

```
 //emit this event inside your success function. pass latitude and longitude with the event 

  window.livewire.emit('set:latitude-longitude', latitude, longitude)
```

After that you can listen to this event from your livewire component class like this:

```
  protected $listeners = [
        'set:latitude-longitude' => 'setLatitudeLongitude'
    ];
```

Then set your passed lat long using setLatitudeLongitude  function inside your livewire component class.

```
public function setLatitudeLongitude($latitude, $longitude) 
{
   $this->latitude = $latitude;
   $this->longitude = $longitude;
}
```

Let me know if you need further explanation :)

Comment: Thanks @fahim152 , I have managed to get the coordinates. However, I am still stuck at this stage. After I get the coordinates I have to do some database queries to get some collections. How do I send this results to the page?

Comment: take a public property  in your livewire component class, and set it null or empty array. 

then query inside your setLatitudeLongitude() function, and store that result into the public property you defined. There you have it. 

( To make code more readable, make another function call fetchCoordinatesData() which takes lat long and do the queries inside! call that function inside your setLatLong !  )  

and Finally dont forget to give my answer as correct and thumbs up if you find it helpful / solve your issue :D

Comment: works like a charm!